# How to create a parent image and scale the child images with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I try to create a parent image that contains child images. These children should fit the parent container also if I adjust the size of the parent.
So if I change the size of the parent, the children should scale automatically. How do I do it with css? Or is it only possible with JavaScript?

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  #welle_o_l {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 26px;
  }

  #welle_u_l {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 26px;
  }
  
  #welle_o_r {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 37px;
    width: 22px;
  }
  
  #welle_u_r {
    position: absolute;
    top: 77px;
    left: 34px;
    width: 24px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img id="welle_o_l" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="1"/>
  <img id="welle_u_l" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="2"/>
  <img id="welle_o_r" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="3"/>
  <img id="welle_u_r" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="4"/>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want the child images to change based on the size of the parent container, then you need to use percentages to size them.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#welle_o_l {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 25%;
  }
#welle_u_l {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 25%;
  }  
#welle_o_r {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 25%;
  }
#welle_u_r {
    position: absolute;
    top: 77px;
    right: 6px;
    width: 25%;
  }
```